# MySQL won't properly GROUP BY on emojis

Tags: mysql, unicode, emoji

I'm storing single emojis in a `CHAR` column in a MySQL database. The column's encoding is `utf8mb4`.

When I run this aggregate query, MySQL won't group by the emoji characters. It instead returns a single row with a single emoji and the count of all the rows in the database.

`SELECT emoji, count(emoji) FROM emoji_counts GROUP BY emoji`

Here's my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `emoji_counts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emoji` char(1) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Is there some special Unicode behavior I'll have to account for?

Comment: Where does the query run from? Do you know if you're encoding correctly on the way in? Or that the data in the table itself is good?

Comment: Right now, running query straight through the console on Sequel Pro. Data in the table looks good -- the emojis display properly with a `SELECT * FROM emoji_counts` query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify an expanded collation in the query, namely `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

This worked:

```
SELECT emoji, count(emoji) FROM emoji_counts group by emoji collate utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

EDIT: That collation isn't available on some server configs (including ClearDB's)... `utf8mb4_bin` also appears to work.

Comment: That is utterly terrifying.